# I have 2 json files and i am deserializing them in c#, how can i make a join

Tags: c#, json, join, blazor, deserialization

I have 2 json files and i am deserializing them separately in blazor c#, how can i make a join. so i can show country name also in page. eg AN = Netherlands .

json file 1 is below

```
{"CountryIso2":"AF","CountryName":"Afghanistan"},{"CountryIso2":"AN","CountryName":"Netherlands"}
```

json file 2 is below

```
{"Name":"something","Start":"2021-11-10T09:00:00","End":"2021-11-14T09:00:00","AdditionalInformation":"Volufda.</br>","Address":{"Information":"fasdfas","City":"Pelh\u0159imov, Vyso\u010dina","CountryIso2":"AN"}}
```

my C# code is

```
public class Event
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }

    public Addressar Address { get; set; }
}

    public class Addressar
    {
        public string Information { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string CountryIso2 { get; set; }
    }

public class Country
{
    public string CountryIso2 { get; set; }

    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

give solutions please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject** method. Start by parsing the json files into **Event** and **Country** objects. Then use the **Select()** method to combine them. For example, you can do something like this:

```
public void MergeFiles()
{
    // Parse the json files into object lists
    var countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(File.ReadAllText("countries.json"));
    var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Event>>(File.ReadAllText("events.json"));
    
    // Create a new list with the result
    var result = events.Select(x => new {
       Name = x.Name,
       Start = x.Start,
       End = x.End,
       AdditionalInformation = x.AdditionalInformation,
       Address = new {
          Information = x.Address.Information,
          City = x.Address.City,
          CountryIso2 = x.Address.CountryIso2,
          CountryName = countries.First(y => y.CountryIso2 == x.Address.CountryIso2).CountryName
       }
    }).ToList();
    
    // Write the result to file
    File.WriteAllText("Result.txt", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

This will produce a file with json text that contains the events with country names information.

Answer (score 0):

your first json file is invalid , you have to fix it

```
[{"CountryIso2":"AF","CountryName":"Afghanistan"},{"CountryIso2":"AN","CountryName":"Netherlands"}]
```

you can add CountryName property to an Addressar class

```
public class Addressar
{
    public string Information { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string CountryIso2 { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

code

```
using System.Text.Json;

Event ev = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Event>(json2);
  
List<Country> countries = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Country>>(json1);
  
ev.Address.CountryName = countries.Where(c=> c.CountryIso2== ev.Address.CountryIso2)
                                  .FirstOrDefault()?.CountryName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
As per the existing structure we can apply a where clause and apply the for single results.If we want to go ahead with multiple results we can make use of foreach in this scenario.Please find the complete c# code.You can format it according to your actual result.
 **Your First Json Should be List:**
**You have to represent like this [ {},{} ]**

**[{'CountryIso2':'AF','CountryName':'Afghanistan'},{'CountryIso2':'AN','CountryName':'Netherlands'}]";**

**Complete C# Code:**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Assessment
{
    class P2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
       string countries =
                "[{'CountryIso2':'AF','CountryName':'Afghanistan'},
                  {'CountryIso2':'AN','CountryName':'Netherlands'}]";
            List<Country> _countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(countries);
            string eventDetails = 
                "{'Name':'something','Start':'2021-11-10T09:00:00','End':'2021-11-14T09:00:00',
                 'AdditionalInformation':'Volufda.</br>','Address':
                 {'Information':'N\u00e1dra\u017en\u00ed 1536, Pelh\u0159imov',
                     'City':'Pelh\u0159imov, Vyso\u010dina','CountryIso2':'AN'}}";
            Event eventData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event>(eventDetails);
            eventData.Address.Country = 
                _countries.Where(p => p.CountryIso2 ==                               eventData.Address.CountryIso2).FirstOrDefault().CountryName;
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventData));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Event
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Start { get; set; }

        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }

        public Addressar Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Addressar
    {
        public string Information { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string CountryIso2 { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string CountryIso2 { get; set; }

        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }
}
```